# How to access Alexa smart home devices in a C# Application?

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

I want to create a C# based **Desktop application** to access all the available Smart Home devices to user's Alexa account.

I found some information on the [Alexa's documentation page](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-discovery.html) but I am not sure how can I use it and will it really return all the available devices (not just the devices associated to a particular manufacturer/skill).

**Question:** How can I connect to the Alexa's user account and retrieve a list of all available devices in it?

Comment: I don't think such API exists.